# call function after jquery selectable is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure a way to call a function after jquery selectable is done doing what is doing (sort or whatever). I need to find out when is done moving things because it seams I can not acces some elements. Here is the code:

i want to call this function to repair the zIndex numbers.. reparaZindex()
I tryed to put it in the start, or update, but nothing works.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        start: function(event, ui) {},
        update: function (event, ui) {}
       });
  });
```

My script works ok, when the page is loaded I can check all the id-s, but after changing the list is not working. Here is a link to see:

(i've put the reparaZindex in stop in the example of above, but is not working )

Comment: I'm confused with what you're saying. Did you try `update: function (event, ui) { reparaZindex(); }` ?

Comment: I think you are searching for this?

    $(this).stop();

Comment: Yes I did tryed ( i put it in update, then in start but nothing works like I said)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this bit of code:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        stop : function(event, ui){
        reparaZindex(); 
        alert("bananas eat children");
   }
       });
  });
```

If you get the alert but your function doesn't work, that means your reparaZindex() is doing something wrong.

---

```
$(function() 
{

    $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({ 

        start: function(event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
    },





        update: function (event, ui) {
        var start_pos = ui.item.data('start_pos');
        var end_pos = ui.item.index();

            var eroare=0;

            //incepe trimiterea la bd a indexurilor

            for(var i=0;i<ui.item.parent().children().length;i++){
                    if(1==0) //eroare
                    eroare=1;
                    var x =ui.item.parent().children()[i];
                     //$(x).find('img').css('z-index',500-i);
                     y=$(x).children()[0];
                     y.style.zIndex=500-i*2;
                     if($(x).children().length>1){
                    c=$(x).children()[1];
                    TEMP=500-i*2+1;
                    c.style.zIndex=TEMP;
                    //alert(TEMP);
                    //alert($(x).children()[1].id)
                    }
                }
            if(eroare==0)//daca bd a upatat indexurile pt start_pos la eng pos
            {
                var copii=ui.item.parent().children();
                for(var i=0;i<ui.item.parent().children().length;i++){
                    //alert(ui.item.parent().children().eq(i).id())
                }


            }
            else {


                }   


    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { $.each($(".sortable > li"), function() {alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id"));}); }

  });
});
```

Comment: Stop is not working at least as good as update (if i call reparaZindez in update it can't see one item, but in stop can't see at all any items except one)

Comment: Stop is an event fired automatically when the sortable is done. It does not see anything because it is an event. Perhaps you should post your reparaZindex(); since most likely your problem is there ;). Put the banana alert in the reparaZindex() function, if it fires, stop works perfect.

Comment: That function works well if I do not change items in the list. ( I know because  I call it when the page starts: window.onload )

Comment: So post your code and function because an event doesn't see things. The problem must be in your zIndex Repair.

Comment: In repzaraZindex all I do is to alert the id of the elements, and I get the id "undefined" if I change the order of the list. Otherwise it works well and it gets me the real id of the elements.

Comment: So when you load the page, the ids are there. Then, after a sortable, they disappear?

Comment: And if I call the function manualy after the list is reordonate it works as good, the problem is that this function from jquery modify things for a short while...

Comment: Not desepear, just can't acces the id from that function

Comment: just a second to uplod the page and i will give you a link

Comment: Help.. I am trying to fix this for hours

Comment: What happens if you do for(var j=1;j<x.childNodes.length;j++)

Comment: No need to include <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> twice

Comment: Look again on the same page

Comment: Well, thaks I will delete it ( this is more like a file to test things)

Comment: @raducup Why do you have random `{` and `}` in that function? Anyways, if you're going to use `.childNodes`, you need to check that the `nodeType` property of that child node is `1`. So in your `j` loop, use `y=x.childNodes[j]; if (y.nodeType === 1) { do stuff };`. Otherwise, it's looping through all node types (including text nodes)

Comment: well, they seem random because I write and delete code a lot to make it work

Comment: that thing with nodeType looks like a good ideea, but in the future I will have more nodes with the same type so is not a very good solution. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am trying to put the z-ingex for the first img element 500, for the first ul list 501, for the secound img 498 etc...

Comment: $(".sortable > ul").each(function(){alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id")}) this is not working...

Comment: do you get an alert at least? or does the each fail?

Comment: oh , its $.each($(".sortable > ul"), function() {alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id")})

Comment: that line of code is not working, i get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: stop: function(event, ui) {
        $.each($(".sortable > ul"), function() {alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id")}))
    }

Comment: not working, i get this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ), if i delete the las ) i get another one

Comment: Minor fix: 
stop: function(event, ui) { $.each($(".sortable > li"), function() {alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id"))}) }

Comment: no copy paste the line again, there is a } and a ) in the wrong order atm

Comment: Is almost 2 AM and stil no fix for it

Comment: Try removing the } at the end of the stop that might fix it

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: I think I got it:

remove $(function() {
that is before $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();

It has no closing tag

You can also add a closing tag for it at the end. Its missing 
});

Comment: like this: stop: function(event, ui) { ($(".sortable > li"), function() {alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id"))}) }  ?

Comment: Sorry man, can't figure what function you mean(sorry for my english)

Comment: Look at original answer above, I put a ----- 
Under I wrote the whole function, but its fixed. So copy&paste that instead of yours :)

Comment: Well I am going to sleep, anyway, thanks a lot for youre time. I will try tomorrow something else if I can think of another way to select that nodes...

Comment: Just do my function so I can see what it gives (it will fix your javascript errors)

Comment: The one that starts on line 5 (or six if you start counting at 1)

Comment: stop: function(event, ui) { $.each($(".sortable > li"), function() {alert("!!!"+$(this).attr("id"));}); }
 I've put this code not working, sorry

Comment: You have to replace the WHOLE function, not just that line. The main problem is that your function above does not close so that is what gives an error

Comment: ok, it did worked, now I have to change the zIndex, thanks a lot!

Comment: so now I can sleep well! Afer hours of debuging :)! Thanks a lot!

Comment: As you can see, if you open the 1st and 2nd drawer the items in the 2nd drawer are over the first drawer, the whole thing was to acces them so I cam change the z-index to fix that bug! Thnx

Comment: But if you notice, the problem was not with sortable, but with your code logic, that is why it is important to post everything even if you think it will be useless.

Comment: I will next time, I was worried it is too much code and nobody will read it

Comment: Its not the length of the code that decides that, its how cleanly written it is. Clean code = most important thing. Even more important than comments.